# XML Schema - Roots elements cannot find declaration of element

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, enterprise-architect

## Overview

I downloaded an XML schema from the Enterprise Architecture Software. One of things I want to do is begin developing XML files that conform to these models presented as XML Schemas.

## Issue

Within the XML file I am linking to the schema. I however get an error `cannot find the declaration of element`. The root element in the schema is `<xs:complexType name="Product">`, however I do notice it has a sibling element called annotation but it wasn't given a name. I still tried using this annotation as the root but got the same issue.

I tried also using "Product Type" as the root element as its the first tag of type element in the schema but got the same error as well. Seems like know of the elements can be used as the root.

## Question

What is it I am getting wrong here? I can't change the Schema as this is the output of the software.

## Schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com/product"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/product product.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>The Product defines the product(s) which are in focus for the Integrated Product Support (IPS) program. Once defined, a Product will then come in one or many Product variants. </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType name="Product">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Product is &lt;&lt;class&gt;&gt; that represents a family of items which share the same underlying design purpose.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="productIdentifier" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>productIdentifier is an identifier that establishes a unique designator for a Product and to differentiate it from other instances of Product.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="productName" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>productName is a name by which the Product is known and can be easily referenced.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="ProductVariant" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ProductVariant">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>A productVariant is a &lt;&lt;class&gt;&gt; that defines a member of a Product family which is configured for a specific purpose and is made available to the market.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="productVariantIdentifier" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>productVariantIdentifier is an identifier that establishes a unique designator for a ProductVariant and to differentiate it from other instances of ProductVariant. </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="productVariantName" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>productVariantName is a name by which the ProductVariant is known and can be easily referenced.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

## XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Product xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/product"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com/product product.xsd">
</Product>
```

## Note

Both the xml and the .xsd file are in the same folder.

Comment: Can you post the diagram of the XSDSchema? You have only declared two complex types, but no element. So there is no valid xml for this xsd.

Comment: From where exactly did you download that schema?

Answer (score 0):

Are you seriously saying that some production software is using the namespace `http://www.w3schools.com/product` in a production schema? That's a pretty appalling design choice.

It's a very strange schema because it defines no global element declarations. So the only way you can write a valid XML is for your root element to contain an `xsi:type` attribute that refers to one of the global type declarations: for example

```
<Widget xsi:type="p:Product" xmlns:p="http://www.w3schools.com/product">  
  <p:productIdentifier>...
```

There are some well-known schemas that use this approach, for example FPML, but it's pretty unusual and in my view questionable.

Comment: I'm not in that specific area but for EA I would not be suprised someone would state what you did ;-)